# Good books of naive set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, book-recommendation

Is there a good book naive set theory which prove important theorems and propositions like:

> - The rational numbers are countable
> - The real numbers are not countable
> - $card \ (0,1)=card\ \mathbb R$
> - The union of countable sets are countable
> - Schröder–Bernstein theorem
> - Other interesting theorems

I would like to find a book not so basic as high school set theory books and not so advanced as *Naive set theory* by Halmos (despide the name this book is not a naive set theory book).

Thanks

Comment: I learned set theory from Axiomatic Set Theory, Takeuti & Zaring, but it may be too rigorous for your liking. Enderton's "Elements of Set Theory" is a bit easier, perhaps it might work for you. (Also, your selection of theorems is mostly about cardinality, which will usually be within just a few chapters in your average set theory textbook.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first half of Irving Kaplansky's book [**Set Theory and Metric Spaces**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821826948) fits what you're looking for. It covers all these topics, and just a little more, but nowhere near as much as the typical books one finds mentioned, such as Enderton's book or Hrbacek/Jech's book. It's a little below the level of Halmos, although not so much that it would be little more than a guide for how to work with unions and intersections of sets (high school level stuff, I would suppose). It's also very well written and not obsessed with mathematical formalism -- there are plenty of well written verbal explanations. Scattered throughout the book are also some very interesting "notes to the reader", such as how differently a typical mathematician tends to view the axiom of choice, Zorn's lemma, and the well-ordering principle despite the fact that are mathematically equivalent (and Kaplansky proves their equivalence in great detail). I seem to recall that there is also a short discussion about some really big cardinals, such cardinals that (when also viewed as ordinals) satisfy ${\aleph}_{\alpha} = {\alpha}.$

A bit longer, but still in the same spirit as Kaplansky's treatment, is [**Classic Set Theory: For Guided Independent Study**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412606100) by Derek Goldrei.

You might also want to look at [**Schaum's Outline of Set Theory and Related Topics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070381593) by Seymour Lipschutz, especially if you want to see a lot of worked problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not as comprehensive as you need, but Smullyan's {\it Satan, Cantor, and Infinity} discusses many of these topics in an understandable yet sophisticated way.

Answer (score 0):

Velleman's *How To Prove It* proves each of these things as well as many more interesting theorems. However, if you're already very familiar with reading and writing proofs then it might be a slow read.

Answer (score 0):

The book on "Topology" by James Dugundji is very good; the first chapter is "Elementary Set Theory", the second is "Ordinals and Cardinals", covering what you need (and in particular your last point).